# Grep first number value from quota -u

Tags: linux, centos, grep, quota

I would like to get first number from:

```
[root@nowosci /]# quota -u testclient
Ograniczenia dyskowe user testclient (uid 7798):
System plików   bloki miękki  twardy  pobł.   pliki miękki  twardy  pobł.
/dev/root  100256  51200000 51200000              34       0       0
```

So it will return just 100256

So far I went to this:

```
quota -u testclient | grep -Eo '[0-9]{6,10}'                          
100256
51200000
51200000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
quota -u testclient | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Good.  Umm, feel free to accept the answer, then, by clicking the tick outline next to it.  My apologies if you are already familiar with the practice!

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it :)

```
quota -u testclient | awk '/\/dev\/root/ {print $2}'
```

Comment: This one is preferable as it specifies the desired mount point.